# Como montar uma Transaction com Commit e Rollback no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, transações, commit, rollback

Estou tentando montar uma transação no Oracle, mas não sei como efetuar um Rollback caso haja um erro em uma das querys. Pesquisei em algum sites, mas não encontrei nada claro e simples que explicasse.

Comecei fazendo assim:

```
DELETE FROM 
  TB_CONFIGURACAO_EXERCICIO_CRON 
WHERE 
  COD_CONFIGURACAO_MODULO IN 
  (SELECT COD_CONFIGURACAO_MODULO FROM TB_CONFIGURACAO_MODULO WHERE COD_CONFIGURACAO = 502);

DELETE FROM
  TB_CONFIGURACAO_MODULO WHERE COD_CONFIGURACAO = 502;

DELETE FROM
  TB_CONFIGURACAO_EXERCICIO WHERE COD_CONFIGURACAO = 502;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estou supondo que você está conectado no Oracle diretamente e não esteja fazendo isso através de uma linguagem de programação como Java ou .NET. Dito isso, seguimos.

Você não precisa ficar preso a procedures para declarar blocos de código com commits ou rollbacks. Você pode usar diretamente na sua IDE SQL preferida. Veja esse exemplo [roubado do stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908533/howto-use-rollback-commit-in-oracle-sql):

```
begin

  statement_zero;

  savepoint my_savepoint;

  begin
    -- if either of these fail, then exception section will be executed
    statement_one;
    statement_two;
  exception
     when others then
       rollback to my_savepoint;
  end;

  statement_three;

  commit;

end;
```

Mas você deve **ficar muito atento** quando você for fazer queries que leia inserções que você acabou de fazer mas que você ainda não tenha feito `commit` dessas inserções. Suas *queries* não conseguirão fazer essas leituras pois o **Oracle não suporta dirty reads**, como descrito abaixo:

> Dirty read: The meaning of this term is as bad as it sounds. You're
>   permitted to read uncommitted, or dirty , data. You can achieve this
>   effect by just opening an OS file that someone else is writing and
>   reading whatever data happens to be there. Data integrity is
>   compromised, foreign keys are violated, and unique constraints are
>   ignored.

Fonte: [Ask Tom](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html).

Comment: Concordo com a parte que você disse que não precisamos ficar presos a procedures, talvez o exemplo que dei não foi o mais feliz; Mas era o que eu tinha ja na mão. Muito bem!

Answer (score 3):

Supondo que voce encontre uma exceção durante o seu processamento, você poderia fazer um rollback nessa linha:

```
PROCEDURE SP_FAZ_ALGO
        (
          pUSU_STATIVO IN OUT USU_USUARIO.USU_STATIVO %TYPE,
          pUSU_CDUSUARIOIN OUT USU_USUARIO.USU_CDUSUARIO%TYPE,
        )
IS
sCreateUser Varchar(200);
bUsuarioExiste Number;
eUsuarioExiste Exception;
BEGIN
       SELECT 
               COUNT(usu_cdusuario) 
               INTO bUsuarioExiste 
        FROM USU_USUARIO 
        WHERE USU_CDUSUARIO = pUSU_CDUSUARIO;

        IF(bUsuarioExiste > 0) THEN
              RAISE eUsuarioExiste;
        END IF;

        SELECT usu_seq.nextval INTO pUSU_IDUSUARIO FROM DUAL;

        INSERT INTO USU_USUARIO
             (
                USU_STATIVO
             )
        VALUES
             (
                pUSU_STATIVO 
             ) ;

        COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
       WHEN eUsuarioExiste THEN
             RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'MINHA EXCEPTION LANÇOU.');
             ROLLBACK;
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
             RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, SQLCODE || ': ' || SQLERRM);
             ROLLBACK;
END SP_FAZ_ALGO;
```